# Can you cherry-pick a hunk or hunks from within a git commit?

Tags: git, git-rebase, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

When I do stage commits in my workspace I usually use the `-p` option to go through each hunk of the changes. I find this useful to confirm my changes and as a check on typos and other silly errors.

I usually `rebase` in my open source development work when a dev branch gets stale. However, sometimes I want to test out something on a throw away branch in my workspace and I don't want the entire branch because it is long and contains many commits that are not yet merged. I could `git cherry-pick` but that appears to grab the ***entire*** commit. Sometimes these commits are large and I don't want the entire thing.

Is there any way to grab the commit via `cherry-pick` but inspect the commit hunk by hunk as it is applied to a staging area before committing?

Presumably the user then stages only the components of the commit that they want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure it's the simplest way, but atomically it could look like

```
# first you cherry-pick without committing
git cherry-pick -n <commit-hash>

# then you unstage everything
git reset

# and stage hunk by hunk as usual
git add -p

# finally you discard everything else
git stash --keep-index
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this seems lime a straightforward way to proceed. I'm surprised there is no `-p` option in git to correspond with the `-n` option. I realize it may have implications if used in conjunction with the `-x` option and may not have been part of the original use case. Either way this could also be scripted so thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't work though if the cherry-pick doesn't apply and you want to only pick hunks that you know can be applied.